# Meaning of output_bps in rawpy.Params

Tags: python, image-processing, libraw

I am new to image processing world and want to use the `rawpy` library for processing some images. I came across `output_bps` param in the postprocess function which does not have any explanation associated in the docs: https://letmaik.github.io/rawpy/api/rawpy.Params.html#rawpy.Params. Except that it can be 8 or 16.

May be that's because its too primitive to be explained? Any explanation of this param will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"bps" stands for "bits per sample", and a pixel in this case consists of three samples: red, green and blue. So you can use `output_bps` to tell `postprocess()` how many bits per sample you'd like to have in the output image, i.e., how much color precision you need. Typically 8 bits is enough, but 16 can be useful if you're going to do any post-processing.